# Group timestamps into sessions with a defined minimum gap between sessions

Tags: sql, postgresql, session

I'm trying to group my timestamp data into user sessions of various lengths where a session end is defined by a minimum time gap between sessions.

So if the thr is e.g. 5 minutes, two timestamps with a 2 minute gap would be considered the same session, while two timestamps with the gap of 6 minutes would be considered two sessions.

I've seen several examples where people try to group into sessions of a certain length, which is kinda easy. But my case is too "online" and I can't figure out what trick to use.

I have a base query defining the timestamps and creating sessions with 1 minute granularity. But I get one long session for each `object`, merging several ones into one long one.

How could I split my long merged session into several ones, with a defined gap of e.g. 5 minutes?

```
SELECT
    count(distinct timestamps.*) as min_spent,
    timestamps.object_id,
    timestamps.user_id,
    min(created_min) as session_start,
    max(created_min) as session_end
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            date_trunc('minute', datetime) as created_min,
            object_id,
            user_id
        FROM timestamp_metrics
        GROUP BY created_min, object_id, user_id
        
    ) as timestamps
    left join objects o on o.id = timestamps.object_id
    left join users u on u.id = timestamps.user_id

GROUP BY object_id, user_id
```

Comment: Can you share sample input data and expected output?

Comment: the `GROUP BY`   fo the inner select doesn't make sense use a `DISTINCT` instead

Comment: The role of `object_id` and `user_id` is unclear. It's also unclear why you truncate to minutes. Also, as always: table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and Postgres version.